# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [attribute name] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [class name]

Tags: jsf, tomcat, ejb

I have created a web application which has `createBook.xhtml` with JSF technology and it uses Managed Beans. In this page user must fill required information in input fields and then hit Submit button. Then this information should be persisted into database by using `doCreateBook()` method. I use Tomcat 7.0 server for this web application.

Let's start first with error message I get, which is:

`javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com.mysite.bookecommerce.beans.BookController/bookEJB] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com.mysite.bookecommerce.beans.BookController].`

**BookController is EJB which code is:**

```
package com.mysite.bookecommerce.beans;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import com.mysite.bookecommerce.entities.Book;

@ManagedBean(name = "BookController")
@RequestScoped
public class BookController implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EJB
private BookEJB bookEJB;

private Book book = new Book();

public String doCreateBook() throws Exception{
    book = bookEJB.createBook(book);
    return "bookCreationSuccessful.xhtml";
}

public void doDeleteBook() throws Exception{
    bookEJB.deleteBook(book);
}

public void doUpdateBook() throws Exception {
    book = bookEJB.updateBook(book);
}

public BookController() {
    super();
}

}
```

**BookEJB class is:**

```
package com.mysite.bookecommerce.beans;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ejb.Stateful;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.mysite.bookecommerce.entities.Book;

@Stateful
 public class BookEJB {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "BookECommercePU", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager em;

public Book createBook(Book book) throws Exception {
    em.persist(book);
    return book;
}

public void deleteBook(Book book) throws Exception {
    em.remove(book);
}

public Book updateBook(Book book) throws Exception {
    em.merge(book);
    return book;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Book> getBooks() throws Exception {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT b from Book AS b");
    return query.getResultList();
}
}
```

**Book is entity class which code is:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long ID;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column(nullable = false, length = 2000)
private String description;

@Length(max = 10)
@Column(nullable = false)
private int isbn10;

@Length(max = 14)
private String isbn13;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String author;

private String publisher;
private int publishYear;

@Column(nullable = false)
private int numberOfPages;

@Column(nullable = false)
private double price;

private boolean illustrations;
private String dimension;
private double weight;
private int quantity;

 //getters and setters
```

**Also faces-config.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0">

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>BookController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.mysite.bookecommerce.beans.BookController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**And finally web.xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>BookECommerce</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The problem seems to be that my web application doesn't find that BookController EJB. How I can fix this? I have read that you must add it in faces-config.xml file but I have added it and still I get this error.

Note that I took all import lines from Book entity class because it would have made code snippet long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to note here:

1. CDI and EJB don't work with plain Tomcat because Tomcat is only a servlet container and not a real Java EE application server like [Glassfish](https://glassfish.java.net/) or [JBoss](https://www.jboss.org/jbossas). In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139050/cdi-on-tomcat-7-does-it-make-sense) you'll find a little bit more details.
2. If you really want to use CDI you'll have to use the annotations from the `javax.enterprise.context` package (e.g. `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped`).
3. The declaration of beans in the `faces-config.xml` is optional in JSF 2+.

Comment: I installed TomEE and now my web application works. Thank you very much :)